# How can I create a query that obtains data from two tables, yet includes records that are unmatched on the other table? Microsoft Access

Tags: microsoft-access

I need a query that displays all data from two tables, and not all records on Table A have matching records on table B. By default, the query *only* displays records that match other records in the tables involved (not unmatched ones).

I want the query to show both: records with matched records in the other table, as well as ones that have no matching recors on the other table.

Is this possible? If so, how can that be made? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The first query is an A **left** join B.
The second query is a B **left** join A where A.joinfield Is Null. The order of the fields in the second query is the same as in the first query.
Then you put these two queries in the Union query.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that my problem has to do with how the tables are joined first. To specify which table goes first, do I need to know SQL? I try, but it seems to me that my queries' SQL needs to be edited.

Comment: Your task is not so complicated that you have to know SQL in detail. Please provide us with your query (the union query), then we can check whether it works, or not. Or would you prefer to see an example?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to:

- Create a query that only displays matched records (as happens by default).
- Then, create a second query with criteria "Is Null", when filtering records for the needed fields.

Finally, create a "union query" (some SQL may be involved) that displays the data from both the first query and the second query.

I'm having trouble getting this to work though: The second query displays no records when I include the "Is Null" command.